# How to set init for maximum script execution, memory limit and max files upload in wordpress

Tags: plugin-development

Am trying to set **maximum execution time**, **memory limit**,  **max upload**  that can be execute by the script. I can do that in php as follows.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300'); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M'); //maximum mb to be consumed by script
ini_set('upload_max_size', '4M'); //maximum mb to be uploaded by script
```

My question is what is the wordpress equivalent ways of doing that. Thanks

Comment: Answer: No. WordPress is not scripting or programming language and is not a server environment. It is just a content management system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

Add the following to wp-config.php:

set_time_limit(300);

Add the following to .htaccess:

php_value max_execution_time 300

Answer (score 0):

You can set all those into wp-config.php file. You can see that file in WordPress root.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300'); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M'); //maximum mb to be consumed by script
ini_set('upload_max_size', '4M'); //maximum mb to be uploaded by script
```

Apart from this you can set that into .htaccess file as well.

```
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value memory_limit 64M
php_value upload_max_size 4M
```

if you have user.ini file you can define those values as well

```
max_execution_time = 300
memory_limit = 64M
post_max_size = 4M
```

Answer (score -1):

The best option that I have was to set  the codes below on top of the page of every script that runs my applications

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300'); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M'); //maximum mb to be consumed by script
ini_set('upload_max_size', '4M'); //maximum mb to be uploaded by script
```